# Folder's taking up way more than it should

Tags: linux, df, du

My server is chugging along with a 5GB drive, and unfortunately, it's 100% full. Going to delete some files, I notice that my Dropbox's taking up way more than it should. `du -hs *` returns:

```
[excel@catfish ~]$ du -hs Dropbox/*
11M     Dropbox/Apps
33M     Dropbox/Cyberduck.app
377M    Dropbox/Documents
2.0M    Dropbox/Games
1.3G    Dropbox/Public
```

This adds up to about 1.8GB, which matches up with my Dropbox size on my other machines. However, running that in my `/home/` returns:

```
[excel@catfish ~]$ du -hs *
2.7G    Dropbox
4.0K    beepsh.c
```

This extra gigabyte of space would really be useful until I get another drive. In the meantime, what's up with the disk usage? I already tried rebooting to clear the file handles, it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a hidden folder named ".dropbox.cache" in your "Dropbox" folder (or any other hidden folders).

If you need a more "userfriendly" disk usage analyzer, try [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the trick! Now to disable the cache :-)